# Unable to get date formatted correctly google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

"G3" cell is currently 2021-10-18 but formatted on Google Sheets to show "Monday, October 18, 2021"

I'm trying to insert a new sheet in the format "Mon - Oct 18" but the following code doesn't give the output I want.

The output that is being given with the below format is "18 - Oct 18". Any ideas on why this is?

```
function myFunction() {
  
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


 var sheetName= ss.getRange("G3").getValue();

 var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetName, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "ddd - MMM dd");

 ss.insertSheet(formattedDate);


}
```

Comment: According to the link in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)), which take you to [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you need to use one or more `E` characters for a "Day name in week".

Comment: Im using this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) which states ````ddd Day of the week, three letter abbreviation (e.g., "Mon").````

Comment: That documentation does not apply to the `Utilities.formatDate` function - which is what you are using in the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a singular `E` to format the date with the day of the week:

```
Utilities.formatDate(sheetName, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E - MMM dd")
```

This will output:

```
Mon - Oct 18
```